# CMake Gcov c++ creating wrong .gcno files

Tags: c++, cmake, gcov

I have a CMakeLists.txt file in which I added:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage -pthread -std=c++11 -O0 ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}")
```

It is generating the report files in:

```
project_root/build/CMakeFiles/project.dir/
```

BUT the files it generates have extentions `.cpp.gcno`, `.cpp.gcda` and `.cpp.o`.

Also, they are not in the same folder as the src files, which are at:

```
project_root/src/
```

When I move the report files to the src/ folder and execute

```
$ gcov main.cpp
main.gcno:cannot open notes file
```

But I get that error message. So I change the `.cpp.gcno`, `.cpp.cdna` and `cpp.o` to `.gcno`, `.gcda` and `.o` and finally I get the following:

```
gcov main.cpp
Lines executed:86.67% of 15
Creating 'main.cpp.gcov'
```

I have over 50 files and can't do this manually for each one.

I need to be able to run gcov once for all files and generate report for all files. I don't care where the files are generated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> It is generating the report files in: project_root/build/CMakeFiles/project.dir/

This is directory where all additional files are built for 'project' executable.

> BUT the files it generates have extentions '.cpp.gcno', '.cpp.gcda' and '.cpp.o'

This is because CMake creates `.cpp.o` object file from `.cpp` source (you may see that running make `VERBOSE=1`. In accordance to `-fprofile-arcs` [option's description](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Instrumentation-Options.html#Instrumentation-Options), data file has suffix `.cpp.gcno`.

> Also, they are not in the same folder as the src files

Data files are created in the same directory with object file.

---

Actually, created files are still work, if you call

```
gcov main.cpp.gcno
```

from the directory with `.gcno` files.

Comment: Well, you are right, it does work. I must have tested it somewhere else then.
Do you know of a way to geta general report of the files not having to run it file by file?
AND, how to avoid the report of stl files, like "stl_map.h" and from the header files of my project?

Comment: `Do you know of a way to get a general report of the files ...` - probably, you want *lcov* utility. Also, you may call `gcov *.gcno`, so it will collect all data files in directory at once. `how to avoid the report of stl files, like "stl_map.h" and from the header files of my project?` - I don't know easy way for doing this. (Complex way is to parse intermediate format of *gcov* output and drop everything related to headers). You may ask another question about this on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thank, I ended up using lcov for the whole generation, though it still gets the coverage of .h files, I'll make another post asking that soon.

Comment: "This is because CMake creates .cpp.o object file from .cpp source" It'd be nice to have an explanation of how to disable that.

Comment: I know why they remains source extension for the object files (for differentiate object files created from sources on different languages), but I don't know how to disable this. You may create new question on Stack Overflow about that.

Answer (score 7):

Apparently the standard CMake behavior to add an extension to give .cpp.o can be changed to replace an extension to give .o by using:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_OUTPUT_EXTENSION_REPLACE ON)
```