# For the input of gcov, any difference between .cpp/.gcda/.gcno

Tags: gcc, gcov

Is there any difference between `gcov foo.gcda`, `gcov foo.gcno` and `gcov foo.cpp`?

According to the [official guide](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-Gcov.html#Invoking-Gcov), we have to put source file `foo.cpp` together with `foo.gcda` and `foo.gcno`, then use `gcov foo.cpp` to generate the report.

But in a CMake Project, object files, `gcda` and `gcno` files are put in a different folder from the source files, as this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37978016/cmake-gcov-c-creating-wrong-gcno-files) presents. So sometimes it's hard to find the source files and move them (as I'm calculating coverage for *Pytorch Project*). Then I tried to skip `.cpp`, just do

```
gcov -i foo.gcda
```

in the CMake folder in which there are `foo.gcda`, `foo.gcno` and `foo.o`. And the result also shows up. I wonder if this result is also correct, or do I have to copy the corresponding `foo.cpp` to this folder and do as official documentation suggests?

Answer (score 1):

You will be getting an output with only the coverage when you run this `gcov -i foo.gcda`.

For eg :-
`File 'foo.c' Lines executed:92.86% of 14 Creating 'foo.c.gcov'`.

And the coverage percentage you are getting is completely correct. The only difference is when you do not put the source file in the same directory commands like :

`gcov -a foo.gcda` will fail with `Cannot open source file foo.c`

This is because with the -a flag you get individual execution counts for every basic block and the output contains the source code along with the number of times each line got executed. If you only want to get the coverage as an output this will work fine but what if you want a HTML based output using tool like lcov, then this method will not work as you will not be able to get the source code.